# Advice needed on choice of Hookup cables

Tags: cables, wire-size

So I am planning to solder hookup cables in my 2.54mm berg connector strip holes in my PCB. I am expecting a current of "max" 10A, and realistically 6A. I need to know which gauge of hookup wires to go for. I am told that the wire in electrolytic capacitors is 25 Gauge and that should be fine here too. Would 25Guage be ok or should I go for 22. Would 22 Gauge fit in the holes, wouldn't it be too wide?

Comment: 22AWG is rated for 8A under many conditions. 24A falls well short of 6A

Comment: @DKNguyen aha, ok, so will a 22AWG fit in my 2.5mm pitch berg connector hole?

Comment: The gauge isn't dependent on "X wire can handle Y current".  It's how much voltage loss your circuit can tolerate.  (unless the wires are so thin they overheat and melt).   24g wire has 25m-ohms resistance per foot.  So if you have, say, five feet of wire, that's 25m * 5 = 250m-ohm or 0.25 ohms resistance just in the wire.  Driving 10A through that, results in voltage loss  V=IR -> V=10A * 0.25 ohm = 2.5V    Can your circuit tolerate losing 2.5V in the wire leads??

Comment: @DribbleNibble If it looks anything like a solderless breadboard, yes.